# How to open another component page when selecting an option in ion-select in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want another component page to open when user select an option from ion-select in ionic3. can someone please help on what to do? thanks in advance. Below is my ion-select code..

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>ENGINEERING &amp; TECHNOLOGY</ion-label>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="engineering">
                <ion-option value="cse">CSE</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="fse">FSE</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="mee">MEE</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="cve">CVE</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="age">AGE</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="che">CHE</ion-option>
                <ion-option value="eee">EEE</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create  a new property to hold changing page id. Get a refernce to the select element with @ViewChild. A method will help to navigate according to select value:
Ok button will react to (ionchange)

Typescript:

```
  @ViewChild('select') select;
  pageId=1;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
  onClick() {

    if(this.pageId===1){
    this.navCtrl.push(ContactPage);
    }
    this.select.close();

  }
```

HTML

```
<ion-select #select (ionChange)="onClick()" [(ngModel)]="engineering">
                <ion-option (ionSelect)="pageId=1" value="cse">CSE</ion-option>
```

....

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-f6fgmf)

Answer (score 0):

In your page.html,

```
<ion-label>ENGINEERING &amp; TECHNOLOGY</ion-label>
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="engineering" (ionChange)="OpenPage()">
<ion-option value="cse">CSE</ion-option>
<ion-option value="fse">FSE</ion-option>
<ion-option value="mee">MEE</ion-option>
<ion-option value="cve">CVE</ion-option>
<ion-option value="age">AGE</ion-option>
<ion-option value="che">CHE</ion-option>
<ion-option value="eee">EEE</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

In your page.ts,

```
  OpenPage() {
    if (this.engineering === 'cse') {
      this.navCtrl.push(CSEPage);
    } else if (this.engineering === 'fse') {
      this.navCtrl.push(FCEPage);
    }
  }
```

If you want to set newly opened page as root page use `this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page)` instead `this.navCtrl.push(Page)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really works but I want the page to open after clicking OK button in the option... any help please.

Comment: @Oluwabukola Hezekiah I updated my answer. can you check now